# 'For' Loop being skipped?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm currently trying to get to grips with C#. I've reached a point where I'm learning about 'for' loops. The problem I'm stuck on is to create the shape below using only 'for' loops and the character '*' only once.

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

The code I've written is below:

```
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column + row < 4; column++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            for (int column = 0; column + row >= 4; column++)
            {
                if (column - row >= 5)
                    break;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

From what I can see, the second nested 'for' loop is being skipped until the first loop is complete.

Replacing the spaces with "O", this displays the following:

```
OOOO
OOO
OO
O
*********
**********
***********
************
*************
**************
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your logic in your second for loop isn't sound; you simply wrote that it won't do anything such that `column + row >= 4` So for the first 4 lines in your second for loop; it's going to not execute.

Comment: I would suggest that you learn how to use the debugger.. also do some refresher reading on `for loops`

Comment: Put your answer as an actual site answer rather than putting it in your question.

Comment: New to this site, sorry. Says I can accept my own answer in 2 days, so I'll wait it out. Wanted to give recognition to those who helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the loop condition for the second nested loop, `column + row >= 4`. Since column starts at zero, the first execution is basically the same as `row >= 4` so for any row < 5 it won't print, which is exactly the conditions of the first loop. This means all the spaces are printed, and then a bunch of stars.

You also don't need the if-statement since that is basically a second loop condition. Something like `for (int column = 0; column <= row * 2; column++)` would make the most sense.

You also should probably re-evaluate the outer loop, since you only want 5 lines, and you will go through 10 lines as-is.

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
    {
        for (int column = 0; column + row < 4; column++)
        {
            Console.Write(" ");
        }

        for (int column = 0; column <= row * 2; column++)
        {
            Console.Write("*");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I completely missed the fact that the condition was never met for the second loop. Finally got a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int row = 0; row < 10; row++)
{
    // This code will only get run for the first 3 rows
    for (int column = 0; column + row < 4; column++)
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    // This code will only get run for rows 4 and greater
    for (int column = 0; column + row >= 4; column++)
    {
        if (column - row >= 5)
            break;
        Console.Write("*");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

What you need to do is ensure your are putting the correct number of spaces followed by the correct number of * for each line.

Hint: You probably only want 5 rows not 10

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < 5 + row + 1; column++)
        Console.Write(column < 5 - row ? " " : "*");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked out a solution:

```
        for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
        {
            for (int column = 0; column + row < 4; column++)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }

            for (int column = 0; column + row >= 0; column++)
            {
                if (column == (row * 2) + 1)
                    break;
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

x...'s solution is probably more appropriate, being clearer and without the need for an if statement and any breaks, but you all helped me reach the answer without too much hand holding, and I appreciate that.

Thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

A simple logic can be like this.

```
for(i=0 to 4) //since five rows
   for(j=0 to 2*i-1) // is in multiple of 1, 3, 5
      print(*)
```